# I want to update image using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update the image into database but unfortunately, the image is not updating into the database. How can I fix it?

**Controller**

```
public function  updateslider(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'select_image'  => 'required'
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('select_image');
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('cms')->put(
        $image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension,
        File::get($image)
    );
    $content = new Sliders;
    if ($request->file('select_image')) {
        $content->slider_image = $image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;;
        $updaterecord = sliders::where(['id' => $content->id])->update(['slider_image' =>
        $content]);
        return back()->with('success', 'Image Updated Successfully')->with('path', $updaterecord);
    }
}
```

**HTML view**

```
      <form   method="post" action=" 
      {{route('update.action',$myslider->id)}}" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data"    >
       @csrf
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
       <div class="card">
       <div class="card-body">
       <h4 class="header-title">Image Upload</h4>
       <input type="file" name="select_image" value=" 
      {{config('e_soft.file_url').$myslider->slider_image}}"   
      class="dropify" data-height="300" />
       </div> <!-- end card-body-->
       </div> <!-- end card-->
        <div class="page-title-right">
        <button   type="submit"  id="update"   class="btn btn-danger 
        waves-effect waves-light col-lg-1">Update</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end row --> 
        </form>
```

Comment: Please provide more information such as your blade file, thoughts or your process or a walk through about whats happening

Comment: please check I have updated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think your problem is that you want to set default value for `<input type="file">` which is not possible. for security reasons you can't set default value for `<input type="file">` so in your case you can check if there is a new image file you put the new one otherwise you just reassign previous slider image here is an example:

```php
$slider = Sliders::findOrFail($id);

if (! empty($request->file('select_image'))) {
    $content->slider_image = $image->getFilename().'.'.$extension;;
} else {
    $content->slider_image = $slider->slider_image;
}
```

So as you can see first we check if there is a new file if so we assign new one otherwise we use the old one.